# How to create an abstract class that extends from a generic class

Tags: c#

There is a class defined in the following way.

```
class MvxViewController<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class, IMvxViewModel
```

I use this class by simply extending, for example:

```
class MyController : MvxViewController<MyViewModel>
```

As I have repeating tasks in every controller I would like to create an abstract class that extends from `MvxViewController` which in turn is extended by every of my controllers (where needed). However, I'm not able to create this abstract class because the syntax is always wrong. Some things I tried so far:

```
a) abstract class BaseViewController<T> : MvxViewController<T>
b) abstract class BaseViewController<T> where T : MvxViewController<T>
c) abstract class BaseViewController<T> : MvxViewController<T> where T : class
```

and others... but I'm still not able to get the syntax correct. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint on the abstract classes needs to be `where T : class, IMvxViewModel` to match the base. For example:

```
abstract class BaseViewController1<T> : MvxViewController<T> where T : class, IMvxViewModel
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have constrained the generic parameter for `MvxViewController` to both `class` and `IMvxViewModel`, you must also extend those same constraints to your abstract class' generic parameter.

```
abstract class BaseViewController<T> : MvxViewController<T> where T : class, IMvxViewModel
```

Constraints are NOT inherited and must be explicitly typed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the constraints the `MvxViewController<TViewModel>` places on `TViewModel` on the type argument of your derived class, as follows:

```
abstract class BaseViewController<T> : MvxViewController<T> where T : class, IMvxViewModel {
    ...
}
```

This is required because C# compiler must check that `TViewModel` argument meets its constraints in the scenario when you derive another class from it.